# Global find and replace in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string in C# that will looks something like this:

```
GET TEXT'somethign' OR TEXT'another' ...
```

Everytime there is a `TEXT'...'`, I want to remove the wrapping `TEXT'...'` so that just the value remains. In other words, if I passed in the string above, the result would be:

```
GET somethign OR another
```

I'm not sure how to remove the wrappers. To the best of my knowledge, the String.Replace function does not support templates. For that reason, I feel kind lost in the approach I should take.

Comment: A regex might work here, but would a `'` character ever appear inside other single-quotes? Does this system use escape-characters at all?

Comment: This looks very much like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Your title says find and replace, but instead it sounds like you want a templating engine.  Are you needing to replace text for a specific purpose (like ETL) or are you trying to use replacing text for a template engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Replace` isn't best suited for this, what you need is a `Regex.Replace`.

```
var input = "GET TEXT'somethign' OR TEXT'another' ...";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "TEXT'([^']+)'", "$1");
```

Comment: Tiny point, I wonder if `TEXT''` would be a valid input. That would require * instead of +